# Authentification in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I would to find some examples of simple authetification in angular 2. With routing, authguard and validation.

Of course, i'am use a search in google, but i find only with auth0 and jwt authentification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a service that knows if the user is logged in or not:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
    private loggedIn: boolean;

    constructor(private router: Router) {
        this.loggedIn = false;
    }

    login() {
        // mechanism to login
        this.loggedIn = true;
    }

    logout() {
        // mechanism to logout
        this.loggedIn = false;
    }

    isLoggedIn() {
        return this.loggedIn;
    }
}
```

If you want to protect some components in your router you should create an AuthGuard like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginService } from './login.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private loginService: LoginService, private router: Router) { }

    canActivate() {
        if (this.loginService.isLoggedIn() !== true) {
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

The guard calls the loginService and gets the information if a user is logged in or not. If the user isn't logged in, the guard tells the router to navigate to the `login`-page.

You need to use `canActivate` ([see docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/CanActivate-interface.html)) to use the guard in your router configs:

```
{
    path: 'app',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    component: ProtectedComponent,
}
```

This is just a simple example for authentication with angular 2.

Answer (score 0):

What i have is a service that holds the state of the app.

Further authentication i create is login with user, passwords. Response from the server returns a token. I store the token, userId is the app state. Then i have this service in each component i use where i need information regarding the user.

An example of such state service. https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/blob/master/src/app/app.service.ts

I use this token to authenticate the user with further requests to the server.

Regards